# Stacking LSTM layers/cells in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to stack LSTM cells in TF, this is what I have:

```py
for layer in xrange(args.num_layers):
    cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(args.hidden_size,
                                  initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer())

    cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(args.hidden_size,
                                  initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer())

    cells_fw.append(cell_fw)
    cells_bw.append(cell_bw)

output = initial_input 
for layer in xrange(args.num_layers):
    ((output_fw, output_bw), (last_state_fw, first_state_bw)) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
        cells_fw[layer], cells_bw[layer], output,
        dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.concat([output_fw, output_bw], axis=-1)
```

This gives me an error which is:

> ValueError: Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/kernel already
>   exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

When I set it to true I get

> ValueError: Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/kernel does not
>   exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=None in VarScope?

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you simply need to create RNNs in different scopes, as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3188):

```py
with tf.variable_scope('lstm1'):
  output, state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3)(input, init_state)
with tf.variable_scope('lstm2'):
  output2, state2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3)(input2, init_state2)
```

Note that the scope should cover *RNN* creation, not *cell* creation.

If you really need to have these RNNs in the same scope, call it with `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` (introduced in the latest versions of tensorflow).